# I'm 99% certain there's some sockpuppet activity on a site, mods are unable to detect it, is there a higher level of escalation?

Tags: support, sock-puppets, stack-exchange-team

I don't want to go into any detail whatsoever on here, I just want to know the procedure for contacting an SE employee to discuss this further.

Who would be the appropriate person to contact, having already discussed it with the mods on the site, who've already asked an SE employee to look into it, with no suspicious activity found?

Answer (score 16):

> who've already asked an SE employee to look into it, with no suspicious activity found

This pretty much closes the deal. Let it go, don't waste the team's time over this unless you have solid proof or something you didn't tell the mods before.

In such case, use the [contact us form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact), choose "Other" and explain what you found. The team would get back to you when they'll have a chance, just be patient.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I figured it might be something like this. I may or may not get around to writing it up as it's hours of work and I don't often have the time. I think I'll just let it go.

Comment: Cheers, unless it's ring of puppets with thousands of rep involved, think it's safe to leave it alone even if something fishy is going on.

Comment: @DumbNic Keep in mind that it's not against the rules to have multiple accounts, it's only a problem if they're voting for each other (or performing certain other types of inappropriate actions between accounts).